# Laravel 4.1 Run migrations and update configuration from package dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, migration, package, config

I'm developing a Laravel 4 package that uses [Sentry 2](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/installation/laravel-4).
In order for [Sentry 2](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/installation/laravel-4) to be installed I have to run migrations and publish their configurations:

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

I would like to allow users of my package to simply run the migrations and publish configs for my own package without having to run that for Sentry 2, or any other package that I might require.

Is there any way to do this? Should this be done at all, or should I keep asking my users to run the migrations/publish confs for every package?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
As promissed, I've followed @AntonioCarlosRibeiro proposal and created a new Artisan command:

```
class SybilInstall extends Command
{
    protected $name = 'sybil:install';
    protected $description = 'Install the sybil package';
    public function fire()
    {
        $this->call(
            'migrate',
            array('--package' => 'cartalyst/sentry')
        );
        $this->call(
            'migrate',
            array('--package' => 'ghunti/sybil')
        );
        $this->call(
            'asset:publish',
            array('ghunti/sybil')
        );
    }
}
```

Now people onlye need to run `php artisan sybil:install` and it will take care of everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your package you can run (Laravel 4.1+):

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('option' => '--package', 'argument' => 'cartalyst/sentry'));

Artisan::call('config:publish', array('argument' => 'cartalyst/sentry'));
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/commands#calling-other-commands

On older versions:

```
Artisan::call('migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry');

Artisan::call('config:publish cartalyst/sentry'):
```

Comment: Nice one Antonio.
Where do you recommend me to put those lines?

Comment: IMO, creating a new artisan command (php artisan package:initialize) would be the best one and you can even run your own migrations from it.

Comment: Will give it a try and post back the results so that anyone can use it in the future if they need.
Thanks again for the help

Comment: This solution is no longer accurate. In Laravel 4.1, you have to pass params in an array such as `Artisan::call('migrate', array('--package', 'cartalyst/sentry'));`. I guess the solution was for an earlier version of Laravel.